# Can nose-parametrized be used with proboscis?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Is it possible to combine
    https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-parameterized
with
    https://pypi.python.org/pypi/proboscis
? Or is there any other way to achieve such functionality with proboscis? I'm aware of this example
https://github.com/rackerlabs/python-proboscis/blob/master/examples/example_factory/tests/service_tests.py
but I would like to have something as simple as this for declaring a test case:

```
@parameterized([
(2, 2, 4),
(2, 3, 8),
(1, 9, 1),
(0, 9, 0),
])
@test
def test_pow(base, exponent, expected):
    assert_equal(math.pow(base, exponent), expected)
```

Comment: +1 for the intriguing subject line.